# Codename One Double with 2 Digits

Tags: double, codenameone

I am having a double value with a constantly varying number of digits, like :

```
double d = 0.6645566; 
double d = 0.664555666766; 
double d = 0.66455887656655566;
```

I want this double to never have more than two digits, like:

```
double d = 0.66;
```

None of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java) seems to work, due to limitations in the CN1 APIs, I suppose.

Many thanks in advance for any kind answer.
How would I achieve this in Codename One?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
String twoDigits = L10NManager.getInstance().format(d, 2);
```

If you still want to keep the decimal you can do:

```
long val = (long)(d * 100);
d = ((double)val) / 100.0;
```